# Elimating double Quotes in a Dataframe

Tags: r, regex, text-parsing

I have a data frame containing 27 columns. All these columns have data that has a structure similar to the one below.

```
principal_amt <- c('"pa": "5975.00"', '"pa": "2285.00"', '"pa": "15822.00"')
closed_accounts <- c( '"ca": 0', '"ca": 3', '"ca": 0')
status <- c(' "loan_status": "Paid" ', ' "loan_status": "Funded"',' "loan_status": "Funded"')
DF <- data.frame(principal_amt, closed_accounts)
```

I want to automatically remove the double quotes present in the observations so that the final data frame has a structure similar to this.

```
principal_amt <- c(5975.00, 2285.00, 15822.00)
closed_accounts <- c(0, 3, 0)
status <- c('Paid','Funded','Funded')
DF_Final <- data.frame(principal_amt, closed_accounts)
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Removing double quotes from `"pa": "5975.00"` results in `pa: 5975.00`, not 5975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readr` package ships with a handy `parse_number` function for such use cases.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = parse_number))

  principal_amt closed_accounts
1          5975               0
2          2285               3
3         15822               0
```

Updated approach for nominal variables - extracting a match. Look behind `: "`, then extract everything until empty string at edge of the word.

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(c(1,3), parse_number),
         across(2, str_extract, "(?<=: \").*\\b"))
 principal_amt status closed_accounts
1          5975   Paid               0
2          2285 Funded               3
3         15822 Funded               0
```

Comment: Edited the question to add a nominal variable that I had initially omitted. How do I go about restructuring the whole data frame?

Comment: @Muli the first argument to `across` is the columns you want to apply the function to. Following the same logic as before, removing excess like `load_status` that is the same for all rows, a regex can be used. I'm no expert at those, but this one seems to work. A tip: if you add a tag to your post *regex* you will most likely get an efficient solution swiftly. Make sure to state clearly the edge cases contained, such as the extra space in the first element of the newly added variable.

Comment: Thanks, I have this code has worked but when I print the structure of the the new data frame, observations in the status column appear as  "\"Paid" ,"\"Funded" or   "\"Cancelled". 

Might you know the reason?

Comment: @Muli probably because the edge cases weren't all covered. you can try to `trimws` to get read of white spaces at the start and beginning of your strings.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen trimws indeed is the solution to this. I had it in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

**Base R**

```
DF <- as.data.frame(apply(
  apply(DF, 2, gsub, pattern = '[^0-9.-]', replacement = ''), 2, as.numeric
))
```

**Output**

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ principal_amt  : num  5975 2285 15822
 $ closed_accounts: num  0 3 0
```

**Addition** (after edit of the OP's question)

In case the `data.frame` contains also character variables next to numeric variables, the following should work.

```
adapt_df <- \(DF) {
  new_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(DF), \(i)  {
    trimws(gsub(pattern = ifelse(grepl('\\d', DF[, i]), '[^0-9.-]', '^\\s.*\\b.*:|\\s$|"')[i], replacement = '', DF[, i]))
  }))
  for(i in 1:ncol(DF)) {
    new_df[, i] <- ifelse(grepl('\\d', new_df[, i]), as.numeric(new_df[, i]), new_df[, i])
  }
  names(new_df) <- names(DF)
  return(new_df)
}
DF <- adapt_df(DF)
```

**Output**

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ principal_amt  : num  5975 2285 15822
 $ closed_accounts: num  0 3 0
 $ status         : chr  "Paid" "Funded" "Funded"
```

Comment: Added a categorical variable to the original dataframe. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Muli I have dapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Muli small side note: you should also add `status` to `data.frame()` in your question ;-)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
principal_amt <- gsub("[^0-9.-]", "", c('"pa": "5975.00"', '"pa": "2285.00"', '"pa": "15822.00"'))
closed_accounts <- gsub("[^0-9.-]", "",c( '"ca": 0', '"ca": 3', '"ca": 0'))
DF <- data.frame(principal_amt, closed_accounts)
```